# Use vagrant with remote virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I would like to use vagrant and let the virtual machine run on a more powerful server than my laptop.

Is it possible to use Vagrant with a remote Virtualbox ?

Answer (score 2):

With the current Virtualbox provider it's not possible.

Possibly you can roughly accomplish the same with different providers, like [AWS](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws) or [Rackspace](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-rackspace).

Answer (score -1):

Looks like [vagrant share](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/share/index.html) is what you need, but I didn't test it.

Comment: vagrant share is interesting, but ultimately not what I want.  I want to on my laptop do `vagrant up` and it brings up a virtual machine on my server.  With vagrant share, I do `vagrant up && vagrant share` on the server and then I can ssh into it from my laptop.